# WooCommerce Variations with Gravity Forms Add-On

Tags: forms, wordpress, gravity, woocommerce

I'm using WooCommerce along with the WooCommerce Gravity Forms Extension.

I've created a multi-page Gravity Form to collect measurement information related to the product from the user.

My product also has multiple Attributes that I am using as product Variations (Color, Buckle Type etc)

Here is the problem...

When you select a Variation option other than the default, fill out the form elements for that page and then click the next button, it goes to page 2 of the form, but the DropDowns for the Variations don't retain the selected options.

They get reset to the default.

Has anyone hit a similar issue? I'm not keen on messing around with the core files for Woo-Commerce to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

you may need this

[WooCommerce Variation Details on Page Product - PLUGIN](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/woocommerce-variation-details-on-page-product/)